# How can I automate multiple Aria2 commands to run consecutively?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe, aria2

I'm trying to execute a command or script that will run a list of aria2 commands consecutively.
I've tried writing a bat/cmd file for it but it always provides an error, specifically:

```
 [httpskipresponsecomand.cc:219] errorcode=3 resource not found.
```

Anyone know how to automate multiple aria2 commands?

For reference this is a template of the commands I'm using:

```
aria2c -P -Z -c -d c:\folder\destination\here -j 5 --check-certificate=false ^
       hxxp://site.com/videofiles/video_[1-200].ts
```

This works with out a problem when I run the commands manually,  one by one, but when I run it in a .bat/.cmd file, I get the above error.

Been struggling with this for awhile now. Hopefully someone knows how to automate multiple aria2 commands to successfully execute in a consecutive manner.

Comment: plz add source code for the batch file.

Comment: @MTG the batch file just has the commands above. For example: ::line 1:: aria2c -P -Z -c -d c:\folder\destination\here1 -j 5 --check-certificate=false hxxp://site.com/videofiles/video1_[1-200].ts ::line 2:: aria2c -P -Z -c -d c:\folder\destination\here2 -j 5 --check-certificate=false hxxp://site.com/videofiles/video2_[1-200].ts  and so forth

Comment: well, thanks, but technically speaking you should edit your question add source code as a quote, to be comprehensive enough for reviews, and to better show any possible errors. "and so forth" does not help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what resource is not found. It could be that brackets are interpreted by your command processor before being passed to `aria2`.

You can store the list of URIs a file. Then you would use [`--input-file`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-i) option to download all the files from the list:

```
aria2c -P -Z --input-file=files-to-download.txt
```

You can use the parametrised URIs in the input file, see the format to [input file](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#id2). Basically, it should look like:

```
hxxp://site.com/videofiles/video1_[1-200].ts
hxxp://site.com/videofiles/video2_[1-200].ts
```

---

Alternatively, you may use a [`for`-loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to generate the list of files:

```
for /L %%i in (1,1,200) do aria2c hxxp://site.com/videofiles/video1_%%i.ts
```